# Using a self-join on a pass-through query in MS Access

Tags: t-sql, self-join, pass-through

I am attempting to perform a self-join on a table on SQL server using a pass-through query from within MS Access. Because the table is very large a linked table in Access simply isn't feasible. Each row of the table represents an individual unit produced by a manufacturing machine and has several years' worth of data, hence many many millions of rows. My goal is to determine, for each instance of a particular category of product produced, the ID of the product produced immediately before it.

In other words, for each row where the type is 20 in Table 1, I want to locate the minimum LineID in Table 2 where the machineID is the same as the current row and the ProductionInterval is the same as the current row. I understand the logic is a little peculiar, but it is the data set I'm working with nonetheless.

Table1 and Table2 are different aliases for the same table

I am receiving a syntax error using the following code on the pass-through query. The message simply says error near '.' which doesn't help me much.

SELECT Table1.LineID, Table1.Type, Table1.MachineID, Table1.ProductionInterval, Min(Table2.LineID) AS MinOfLineID, Table2.Type
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table2 ON (Table1.MachineID = Table2.MachineID) AND (Table1.ProductionInterval = Table2.ProductionInterval)
GROUP BY Table1.LineID, Table1.Type, Table1.MachineID, Table1.ProductionInterval, Table2.Type
HAVING (((Table1.Type)='20') AND ((Table1.ProductionInterval)>(getdate()-365)) AND ((Table2.Type)='0'));

I am reasonably comfortable using MSAccess but am not very experienced in writing SQL code. Any guidance anyone can give will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm no Access guru, but does Access allow you to INNER JOIN on two fields using AND? I would think that the second condition belongs in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes it does. Interestingly, the same query works fine in Access (using a smaller sample table).